# Issue with XML parsing in python

Tags: python, xml

I'm having difficulty parsing an XML tree using xml.etree.ElementTree in Python. Basically, I'm making a request to an API that gives an XML response, and trying to extract the values of several elements in the tree.

This is what I've done so far with no success:

```
root = etree.fromstring(resp_arr[0])
walkscore = root.find('./walkscore')
```

Here is my XML tree:

```
<result>
    <status>1</status>
    <walkscore>95</walkscore>
    <description>walker's paradise</description>
    <updated>2009-12-25 03:40:16.006257</updated>
    <logo_url>https://cdn.walk.sc/images/api-logo.png</logo_url>
    <more_info_icon>https://cdn.walk.sc/images/api-more-info.gif</more_info_icon>
    <ws_link>http://www.walkscore.com/score/1119-8th-Avenue-Seattle-WA-98101/lat=47.6085/lng=-122.3295/?utm_source=myrealtysite.com&utm_medium=ws_api&utm_campaign=ws_api</ws_link>
    <help_link>https://www.redfin.com/how-walk-score-works</help_link>
    <snapped_lat>47.6085</snapped_lat>
    <snapped_lon>-122.3295</snapped_lon>
</result>
```

Essentially, I'm trying to pull the walkscores from the XML document but my code isn't returning a value. Does anyone with experience using ElementTree have any advice to help me extract the values I'm after?

Sam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XML appears to be malformed. But if I replace instances of `&` with `&amp;`, then it's parseable:

```
>>> from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
>>> tree = ET.fromstring(xml)
>>> tree.find('./walkscore').text
'95'
```